# How to use jquery Datepicker in web control in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker, web-controls

i am creating a web-control and i want to use jquery date-picker on this control, i have tried the below things:
1). apply all the required jquery code in web-control(**but it does not work for me.**)
2). apply all the required jquery code in page where i am calling that web-control(**but it does not work for me.**)

Please help me,

Actually what is my purpose to do it is:
i want to create a generic module for search, to which i will just pass the name of table it would be work automatically, what i have completed up to now is:

1). bind all the columns in a dropdown list 
now what i want to do is: if the column type is DateTime then it will show a textbox with jquery calendar.

Please help me to resolve this problem, My code is:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpColumnName" Width="150px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpColumnName_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpOperation" Width="150px" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCondition" Width="150px" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Or" Selected="True" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="And" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateSearch" CssClass="myClass" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddConditionToSearch" runat="server" Text="AddToSearch" OnClick="btnAddConditionToSearch_Click" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Page's code is :

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <Search:ctrlSearch ID="cntrlSearch" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

Jquery code is:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    // Place here the first init of the DatePicker   

    $('.myclass').datepicker();


});

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker 

    $('.myclass').datepicker();


}
```

Please help me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate your date picker by a class selector.This is much easier than trying to locate ids.In case you have your controls sandwiched in an update panel you have two initialize the datepicker twice.Do this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {


        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        // Place here the first init of the DatePicker   

        $('.myclass').datepicker();


    });

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker 

        $('.myclass').datepicker();


             }
</script>
```

Markup`

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateSearch" CssClass="myClass" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
```

See demo files [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/WebApplication3.zip)

Comment: Where are your query scripts located.They should be on the master page.And indicate if you are using update panels.

Comment: i have updated the code, now i can view the div in html rendered using firebug but still not able to display the datepicker

Comment: Can you please show me the js files you are using.Put this code on the main aspx page.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a dropbox of  demo files.I can't see why it should not work.

Answer (score 1):

Check like this

```
$("#<%=txtSearchText.ClientID%>").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be because asp.net changes the names and the ID's of elements which are nested in Controls & master pages etc.

Open the source of your page, find the control and double check the ID.

Or as an alternative add a css class to the element and look for that instead of the ID with jQuery.

JA

Answer (score 0):

visit this page [jquery-ui-datepicker](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-tr.js?r=3004&spec=svn3727) -> It is ui code. Save this code block as a js file. then source it on your aspx page.

```
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-tr.js" type="text/javascript"></script> like this.

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#<%=txtBirthday.ClientID%>').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-100:-17",
                defaultDate: new Date(1980, 01, 01)
            });

});
```

and here is the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#TextBox1" ).datepicker();
  });
  $(function() {
    $( "#TextBox2" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```