# Using Datepicker in Textbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2008

Here I am trying to create a page with a textbox where I've an idea to show a CalendarExtender (like in AJAXToolkit) but now I'm trying to get it by using JQuery, the problem is, I can't make the Calendar UI to pop out when I clicked the textbox, my upper aspx page is looking like this:

```
<link href="../Support/StyleSheet/PageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker({
    });
</script>
```

and the textbox that I'm trying to use is:

```
  <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="120px" height="25px">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CbOutboundOn" Text=" Outbound On" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" class="style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=":"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="200px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbOutboundOn" runat="server" Width="194px" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td width="645px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I think it's good enough, but it isn't, I can't get the calendar to show when I click the textbox in "TbOutboundOn", a friend suggested the stylesheet is the issue, but I don't quite understand, can anyone help with my problem? Btw, I used http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default as my reference.

I already tried to copy all the stylesheet referenced by jqueryui's datepicker sites, and combine it with my own stylesheet, but it still not working. I try to use only the stylesheet provided in jqueryui datepicker too, but still no luck.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you get any error?
Have you included `datepicker.js` ?

Comment: `$("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker({` missing some params another suggestion is use this way: `$("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker();`

Comment: you are missing the jquery ui css file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css

Comment: @vimalnath I didn't use datepicker.js because the example in http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default doesn't include it, do I have to?

Comment: @jai I fixed it and nothing change, anything else?

Comment: @ArunPJohny if I use that, will the previous style that I use in the code, dissapear or overlap?

Comment: @Abie Giordano see my answer or as suggested above by `Arun`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#TbOutboundOn').datepicker();

//or

$('#TbOutboundOn').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });

});
```

u can find other parameter to modify ur datepicker here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Sorry mr @vond ritz I still can't get the datepicker to show, with or without the parameter

Comment: still no luck sir, maybe it has something to do with the stylesheet/css?

Comment: can you debug it in firebug? and tell me what exception it will throw.

Comment: it runs fine, no anything weird whatsoever, it just won't show the datepicker UI when I click the textbox

Comment: so weird behaviour... ok let me think of it again.

Comment: I've fixed it myself, turns out there's is a problem in the javascript  jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.js I referenced to, but since I'm using your answer's solution, I'll pick yours, thank you.

Comment: @Abie Giordano good that you fixed it. sorry if i can't help you further enough. thanks for picking my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your id is being mangled.Use a css class selector. See how I helped another user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219801/how-to-use-jquery-datepicker-in-web-control-in-asp-net/15220011#15220011)  and you can use the demo which takes care of update panels.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
$(".clDate").datepicker(); 
         }   
</script>


  <asp:TextBox ID="TbOutboundOn" runat="server" CssClass="clDate" </asp:TextBox>
```

See demo [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/WebApplication3.zip)

Website demo version [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/Website.zip)

Comment: what do you mean by css selector? can you make an example using my code? sorry I'm a newbie in jquery

Comment: Did you follow the hyperlink in the answer I gave. Download the demo files.Are you using update panels.Oh, I meant a class selector.$(".clDate") is a class selector which will attach itself to textboxes with a css class called clDate.

Comment: Have you tried using the class selector as @AbideMasaraure suggested above? or change your `$("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker()` to `$("#<%= TbOutboundOn.ClientID%>").datepicker()`

Comment: @AbideMasaraure I can't open the solution for the WebApplication 3 and I'm currently not using updatepanel, but I plan to.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat I tried changing the script as you told me, still not working :(

Comment: Open  it as a website if you cant open the solution.Which version of visual studio are you using.

Answer (score 1):

Update following code :
Your Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker({
    });
</script>
```

Update using following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker();    
</script>
```

Ajax response and Date piker code :

```
<tr>
                    <td align="left" width="120px" height="25px">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CbOutboundOn" Text=" Outbound On" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" class="style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=":"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="200px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbOutboundOn" runat="server" Width="194px" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td width="645px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker();    
</script>
```

Comment: Is Your html coming from Ajax request and code you have added in header part of page? If yes please add code in your ajax response page in below, it will resolve your problem. If it is working please mark accepted please.

Comment: Also you should add style sheet as you can see in your reference, for calendar object  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default                     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                             <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Remove cookies and cache of browser.

Comment: removed the cookies and cache, still no luck :(

Comment: Write the step how your process running, possibly I can resolve.

Answer (score 1):

See you have to use the css file for calendar too, you are missing the default closing of the calendar `();`:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#TbOutboundOn").datepicker();  //<-- missing default closing this way.
  });
</script>
```

Comment: but I have a stylesheet too, I already tried to mix both but it still didn't work :(